# Using triple integrals to calculate volume of the body $z \geq x^2 + y^2 \quad, \quad z\leq 2-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

I'm asked to calculate the volume of the body defined by $$z \geq x^2 + y^2 \quad, \quad z\leq 2-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
**My attempt**: I find the intersection:

Using the first condition I get: 
$$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 2-z \iff x^2 + y^2 = (2-z)^2$$
Using the second condition with the first I get: 
$$z = 4 - 4z + z^2$$
Solving for z nets me
$$z_1 = 4$$
$$z_2 = 1$$
I realize $z_2 = 1$ is the only real intersection.

Switching to polar coordinates, I calculate the volume of the bottom half ($0 \leq z \leq 1$):

$$\int^1_0(\int^{2\pi}_0(\int^{\sqrt{z}}_0r\cdot dr)d\theta))dz = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

I calculate the volume of the top half in the same fashion: 
$$\int^2_1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2-z} \approx 4.83\pi$$

The resulting volume is approximately $\frac{\pi}{2} + 4.83\pi = 5.33\pi$
However, the answer is supposed to be $\frac{5}{6}\pi$

Now, I've got two **questions**.

1. Why did I get $z_1$ in the beginning when it's obviously no intersection between the two graphs?
2. Where am I going wrong in calculating the volume? I know there are better ways to calculate the volume, but I want to know why my way doesn't work to get a better grasp of the concept.

Comment: It's better to put the $r$ on the outside. You get that $r\in[0,1]$ because you need $r^2<2-r$ or $(r+2)(r-1)<0$ so $r\in[-2,1]$. Then $z\in [r^2,2-r]$

Comment: When you square something you end with a false root.

Answer (score 1):

Better to put the $z$ part on the inside.

Let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then you need $r^2\leq z\leq 2-r$ or $(r+2)(r-1)=r^2+r-2<0$ so you need $r\in[-2,1]$. But you already know $r\geq 0$ so you really need $r\in[0,1]$.

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} r\int_{r^2}^{2-r} \,dz\,dr\,d\theta$$

The result is $$2\pi \int_{0}^{1}r(2-r-r^2)\,dr=2\pi\left(1-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{5\pi}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

When you search for the intersection it is better to do it like this: $z=x^2+y^2$, so $z=2-\sqrt{z}$. If we put $t=\sqrt{z}$, then we get $t^2+t-2=0$, that is $t=1$ or $t=-2$. It is now clear there is only one solution. You have to be careful with squaring things.

$\displaystyle V=\iiint dxdydz=\iint\limits_{proj}(\int_{x^2+y^2}^{2-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dz)dxdy=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(2-r-r^2)rdrd\phi$,

because the projection is the unit circle. So $0\le r\le1$ and $0\le\phi\le2\pi$.

Comment: Can you sketch this body? It looks like ice cream cone with one scoop of ice cream, turned upside down. There is no need to divide it into two parts in order to calculate the volume. You can do it in one step.